# How to achieve same battery life on Ubuntu LTS 16.04 as Windows 10 using Nvidia graphics adapter?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, battery

> How to achieve same battery life on Ubuntu LTS 16.04 as Windows 10 using Nvidia graphics adapter?

I've tried disabling the Nvidia 940MX in BIOS, but there is no option available to do this.

I know that Ubuntu comes with Nvidia drivers installed (Nouveau), however the performance and battery life are much worse compared to Windows 10 with original Nvidia drivers.

Is it possible to disable the Nvidia graphics adapter completely when running Ubuntu, such that only the Intel graphics card consumes power?

In this case, I will achieve Windows-like battery life, right?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, it's not impossible, and may be in time, battery life will improve. However, practically, it is next to impossible to do what you want in any reasonable time span.

Comment: Install `nvidia-375` and you will be on Intel.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install nvidia-375
```

then reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

The system will run on Intel and Nvidia will not consume power unless you enable it manually.